# Download a file in php not working

Tags: php, download

I develop a code to download a MP3 file from server. The code works in old server but not works in New Server. It shows 0 bytes when i try to download a fine

i send a download link through HTTP Post methos

www.example.com/download.php?dlink=http://www.example.com/music/sample.mp3

Here is the code i used

```
    ob_start();
    if(isset($_REQUEST['dlink']))
    {
        $file = $_REQUEST['dlink'];
        header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
        header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
        header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
        header('Expires: 0');
        header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
        header('Pragma: public');
        header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
        ob_clean();
        flush();
        readfile($file);
         exit;
    }
ob_flush();
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: what is $file here readfile($file)?

Comment: $file = $_REQUEST['dlink'];
I missed this line now i added.. please look at the question....

Comment: are you trying to output file, which is to be fetched another server? or is file located in that server?

Comment: File Located in same server. If is use the new server's Download file  in old server it works...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not pass the absolute url in dlink parameter as you cannot read file from remote server.

use this url www.example.com/download.php?dlink=music/sample.mp3

assuming the executable file in root directory.

Comment: Thanks it works fine.. But same code is working on another server by passing Absolute Url... thats y i ask this.. .Anyway thanks Sir

Comment: Close this ticket if your problem is solved by accepting this answer